# Copy symbolic files pointing to one source path1 to different source path2 in destination folder

Tags: symbolic-link

I want to copy directory/folder structure (A) which contains regular files and symbolic files to another directory B.
But while copying from one path to different path, I want symbolic files to point from source ABC to source XYZ.

Example:
Source:

```
A———
    |
    regular_file1.txt
    regular_file2.txt
    regular_file3.txt
    symlink_file1 —> /a/b/c/orig_file1.txt
    symlink_file2 —> /a/b/c/orig_file2.txt
```

After copy I want the destination as follows:

Destination B

```
B——-
    |
    regular_file1.txt
    regular_file2.txt
    regular_file3.txt
    symlink_file1 —> /x/y/z/orig_file1.txt
    symlink_file2 —> /x/y/z/orig_file2.txt
```

Here symbolic links files are pointing to new path ( /x/y/z) instead of original(/a/b/c).

Please let me know.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You could realize that if you had created the symlinks with `-r` option and used relative links instead, so the `symlink_file1`, for example, would refer to `../../orig_file1.txt`. And you also have to use the `-P` (no-dereference) option when copying.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, relative links will not work. The first set of symlinks are pointing to local path in machine A, whereas destination files should point to some NFS path which can be accessible from any machines in the network.